# Confusing Coefficients in infinite sum

Tags: summation, generating-functions

Consider:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^k}}{\prod_{i = 0}^k (x^{2^i}+1)}$$
For $x>1$.

The first term is $\frac{x}{x+1}$ which can be expanded as $x-x^2+ \cdots$. Every term after the initial of the initial sum has at least $x^2$ in the numerator so it follows that the big sum should have a $x$ term when simplified.

According to $pg. 170$ ($180$ in the file) of the book here:
https://cambomaths.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/red-book-of-mathematical-problems-the-dover-books-on-mathematics-williams-hardy-2010-0486694151-185p.pdf

We have the sum is actually $1$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^{2^k}}{\prod_{i = 0}^k (x^{2^i}+1)}
&=(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^{2^k}}{(x-1)\prod_{i = 0}^k (x^{2^i}+1)}\\
&=(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^{2^k}}{x^{2^{k+1}}-1}\\
&=(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{x^{2^k}+1}{x^{2^{k+1}}-1}-\frac 1{x^{2^{k+1}}-1}\right)\\
&=(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{x^{2^k}-1}-\frac 1{x^{2^{k+1}}-1}\right)\\
&=(x-1)\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac 1{x^{2^{n+1}}-1}\right)\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1
\end{align}

Comment: That's not my question, why do we have a $x$ in the first term and where does it go?